# Align CN1 Component depending on viewable area

Tags: layout, codenameone

I would like to align a component *initially* relative to the visible part of the containing parent (`Container`). The containing parent is planned to be a scrollable Tabs page but only that component should be visible initially on the page when selecting the tab.

In my example I want to position a `Container` (variable: `root`) at the **bottom** of the visible area of its parent. My current approach is to get the height of `root` and the height of `root.getParent()` and then set its top-margin as: `root.getUnselectedStyle().setMarginTop(parentsHeight - rootsHeight);`, but the result is not as expected. How can I manage this?

check the illustrations below:

[intention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuQ7y.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npj0I.png)

Note: when I add the `root` component programmatically then my approach works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I could detect the cause of the problem. The descirbed approach is correct, but I also had to pay attention for a specific point! Beneath the taps bar I have an additional component by default which gets hidden when initializing the containig form. Thus `parentsHeight` is lower than expected because I missed to revalidate the containing layout.